# If $H$ is a subgroup and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ but it need not be normal

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups

I am looking for a simple counter example to prove that if $H$ is a subgroup and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $HK$ is not necessarily a normal subgroup of $G$, though it would always be a subgroup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: find a non normal subgroup of a group $G$, and take $K=\{e\}$....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's really a nice example.  Can you give an example using a non-trivial subgroup as well?
 Thank you for the interest.

Comment: Find a non-normal subgroup of a group $G$. Take $K=G\times\{e\}$ in $G\times G$.

Comment: And of course, find any group $G$ with a quotient in which not every subgroup is normal. Pull back.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Take $K=\{e\}$ and $H$ as any non-normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Thank you for the interest. Can we construct an example using the non-trivial case?

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha What have you tried?